# Verify MongoRestore command worked in shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I have a nightly cron job that runs a `mongodump` on a production database and then a `mongorestore` to a sandbox environment. I'm currently dumping output to `/dev/null`.

Is there any way to shell into the db and verify the `mongorestore` worked. I'm looking for some way to see "a mongorestore was ran on this DB by admin at ..."

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Redirect the output a simple file instead of /dev/null and check the content of it.

Comment: yeah, was just wondering if there was any other way. Don't have access to the crontab atm

Comment: If you don't have access to the crontab, then this would block any solution you may get here.